# TCP congestion window size: strange behaviour

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

I am playing with various TCP algorithms using Netkit.

There are two machines, **c1** and **c2**, connected by a router with forced 200ms delay. Program on **c1** is sending 100-byte packets to **c2** each 1ms (TCP_NODELAY is turned on). Reno is used as congestion control on both machines.

According to tcpdump, only first 2 packets are sent immediately (200 bytes), then **c1** stops sending and waits for ACK. Receiver's window is about 2MSS (MSS=1460), so I guess it's CWND that prevents **c1** from sending further packets.

According to Reno specification, initial CWND is 1MSS. Am i missing something there?.. Even sending 1-byte packets gives same picture, 2 packets are sent and then sender waits for ACK. May it be that initial CWND size is determined by initial segment size, not MSS?

`ip route show cache` shows something like

`cache mtu 1500 rtt 361ms rttvar 360ms cwnd 5 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64`

I wonder if it means that CWND=5MSS?

Answer (score 1):

From the [RFC 2581](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2581.txt)

> IW, the initial value of cwnd, MUST be
>   less than or equal to 2*SMSS    bytes
>   and MUST NOT be more than 2 segments.
>
> We note that a non-standard,
>   experimental TCP extension allows that
>   a    TCP MAY use a larger initial
>   window (IW), as defined in equation 1 
>   [AFP98]:
>
> ```
>   IW = min (4*SMSS, max (2*SMSS, 4380 bytes))           (1)
> ```
>
> With this extension, a TCP sender
>   MAY use a 3 or 4 segment initial
>   window, provided the combined size of
>   the segments does not exceed    4380
>   bytes.  We do NOT allow this change as
>   part of the standard    defined by
>   this document.  However, we include
>   discussion of (1) in    the remainder
>   of this document as a guideline for
>   those experimenting    with the
>   change, rather than conforming to the
>   present standards for    TCP
>   congestion control.
>
> **SENDER MAXIMUM SEGMENT SIZE (SMSS):** 
>   The SMSS is the size of the
>         largest segment that the sender can transmit.  This value can be
>         based on the maximum transmission unit of the network, the
>   path
>         MTU discovery [MD90] algorithm, RMSS (see next item), or other
>         factors.  The size does not include the TCP/IP headers and
>         options.

You might want to check how your implementation is calculating SMSS.

Comment: So, the initial window size is determined by the size of first segment sent?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Linux measures cwnd in "segments" in this case - so as soon as you have sent two segments to flight, then your cwnd is closed for new data.

Answer (score 0):

The initial window is 2. The reason why it is not 1 has to do with delayed acks. The receiver usually waits for two data packets before sending an ack. If the initial window is 1 the ack will be sent after a default time often much larger than necessary. This adds unnecessary delay and messes with ack-clocking.